# String to new object with parameters

Tags: java, reflection

How do i create a new instance of an object from a string?

I want to do this:

```
Event event = new Event("hello");  
event.setName("nice!");
```

but only having

```
String object = "Event";  
String object_variable_name = "event";  
String object_params = "hello";
```

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a Class Object from the Class Name in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438420/how-to-get-a-class-object-from-the-class-name-in-java)

Comment: You can do it using reflection. Here is another post which may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211450/java-reflection-instantiate-a-new-object-with-specified-type

Comment: You would have to write your own string to object interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instantiate a class with the reflection API. But you need the full class name, the simple name (= with no constructor) is not enough.

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("com.example.Event");
Constructor constructor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
Object instance = constructor.newInstance("hello");
```

Assigning it to a variable where the variables name and type are stored in Strings is not possible. The usual pattern to implement this is to use a map:

```
Map<String, Object> events = new HashMap<String, Object>();
events.put("event", event);
```

Comment: This looks good, but this line "Event event = (Event) constructor.newInstance("hello");" assumes that I know the type is Event, but I only have the string value

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.lang.Class's getConstructor isnstead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you get the class instance (so you can call the constructor): [How to get a Class Object from the Class Name in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438420/how-to-get-a-class-object-from-the-class-name-in-java)

Now you can you the Beans API to get the getter for the property `name`. See this question: [Java Reflection: Instantiate a new object with specified type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211450/java-reflection-instantiate-a-new-object-with-specified-type)

Or you can use [reflectasm](http://code.google.com/p/reflectasm/) or [reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) or [commons-beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) to make your life much more simple